# Relation '_' does not exist

Tags: postgresql, typeorm, next.js13

My setup has the following:

1. Nextjs @13
2. Typeorm
3. PG for DB

I am getting following errors when trying to make and DB query.

```
Error getting user from headers QueryFailedError: relation "s" does not exist
    at PostgresQueryRunner.query (/var/task/.next/server/chunks/7143.js:85:84473)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async SelectQueryBuilder.loadRawResults (/var/task/.next/server/chunks/7143.js:112:262083)
    at async SelectQueryBuilder.getRawMany (/var/task/.next/server/chunks/7143.js:112:234275)
    at async SelectQueryBuilder.executeEntitiesAndRawResults (/var/task/.next/server/chunks/7143.js:112:257732)
    at async SelectQueryBuilder.getRawAndEntities (/var/task/.next/server/chunks/7143.js:112:234667)
    at async SelectQueryBuilder.getOne (/var/task/.next/server/chunks/7143.js:112:234886)
    at async getUserFromRequest (/var/task/.next/server/chunks/1077.js:1:428)
    at async GET$1 (/var/task/.next/server/app/api/profile/route.js:1:1822)
    at async /var/task/node_modules/@sentry/nextjs/cjs/common/wrapRouteHandlerWithSentry.js:52:32 {
  query: 'SELECT DISTINCT "distinctAlias"."S_id" AS "ids_S_id" FROM (SELECT "S"."createdAt" AS "S_createdAt", "S"."updatedAt" AS "S_updatedAt", "S"."id" AS "S_id",
```

and

```
QueryFailedError: relation "g" does not exist
    at PostgresQueryRunner.query (/var/task/.next/server/chunks/7143.js:85:84473)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async SelectQueryBuilder.loadRawResults (/var/task/.next/server/chunks/7143.js:112:262083)
    at async SelectQueryBuilder.executeEntitiesAndRawResults (/var/task/.next/server/chunks/7143.js:112:259000)
    at async SelectQueryBuilder.getRawAndEntities (/var/task/.next/server/chunks/7143.js:112:234667)
    at async SelectQueryBuilder.getMany (/var/task/.next/server/chunks/7143.js:112:235769)
    at async getData (/var/task/.next/server/app/admin/page.js:1:2581)
    at async Admin (/var/task/.next/server/app/admin/page.js:1:2734) {
  query: 'SELECT "g"."createdAt" AS "g_createdAt", "g"."updatedAt" AS "g_updatedAt", "g"."id" AS "g_id", "g"."fileLocation" AS "g_fileLocation", "g"."jobTitle" AS
```

This happens whenever I have any DB query.  I have verified that these entities exist. My guess is that this is happening because for whatever reason, next compiler is now shortening my variable names and even though I am making calls through the repository pattern, the table names are being shortened as `g` and `s`, `o`, etc. and that is causing the problem.

I have rolled back `pg`, `typeorm` and `nextjs` versions but same issue.

Comment: Please show the full SQL statements being executed: they're missing the all important FROM clause